# How to get a Unix Timestamp from a specific date - PHP?

Tags: php, smarty, unix-timestamp, mktime

The Unix Time Stamp generated by my MKTIME is not generating correctly

> (European format)
>
> Date Submitted: 15/02/2014 19:00
>
> Unix Code: 1392508800
>
> This returned date is: 16/02/2014 00:00:00
>   Code it should of returned is: 1392490800

Code Used
After form is submitted values are captured and assigned...

```
if ($_POST['Callbacl']){

    $CID=$_POST['ID'];
    $Notes = $_POST['callbacknotes'];

    $Time_H = $_POST['Time_Hour'];
    $Time_M = $_POST['Time_Minute'];
    $Date_Day = $_POST['Date_Day'];
    $Date_Month = $_POST['Date_Month'];
    $Date_Year = $_POST['Date_Year'];

    $Appt = mktime($Time_H, $Time_M,00, $Date_Month, $Date_Day, $Date_Year);
    echo $Appt . "<br>";
    die;
}
```

Post values

```
     Array ( 
    [ID] => 1 
    [Time_Hour] => 19 
    [Time_Minute] => 00 
    [Date_Month] => 02 
    [Date_Day] => 15 
    [Date_Year] => 2014 
    [callbacknotes] => 
    [Callback] => Call Back 
    )
```

Comment: try like this to set a date format to unix:  `$yourdate->format('U');`

Comment: Simplify your sample. Get all time related values, and post only them, result `mktime` returns and why you think it's incorrect. How you get the values doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you show us the output of: print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (02/15/2014 19:00,00) at position 17 (0): Unexpected character' in /home/a5556232/public_html/clients_search_client.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /home/a5556232/public_html/clients_search_client.php(57): DateTime->__construct('02/15/2014 19:0...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/a5556232/public_html/clients_search_client.php on line 57

Comment: Milan Babyskov:

Array ( [ID] => 1 [Time_Hour] => 19 [Time_Minute] => 00 [Date_Month] => 02 [Date_Day] => 15 [Date_Year] => 2014 [callbacknotes] => [Callback] => Call Back )

Comment: Set your default timezone `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose to your time zone in php.ini is not your preferred one.
Try to set a proper time zone in php.ini or to add the following code at the beginning of your block.

```
date_default_timezone_set('your time zone');
```

There is the list of supported time zones in PHP:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Turns out that is the correct answer sir; hats off to you
I just cant seem to understand why a timezone would affect the count of seconds between 00:00:00 01/01/1970 and the date supplied (Shouldnt the value be the same no matter where in the world you live) since every one has 60 seconds in 1 minute and 60 minutes in 1 hr etc etc

Any how thank you

Comment: PHP mktime returns the difference between 00:00:00 01/01/1970 UTC and provided date in your chosen timezone.